# Ajax to implement like function on a blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, html-table

Problem: Ajax is not behaving as it should be.

**PostIndex:**

```
<tr>
  <td><%= post.name %></td>
  <td><%= post.created_at.strftime("%Y/%m/%d, %I:%M%p") %></td>
  <td><%= post.view %></td>
  <td id="post_like_<%= post.id %>"><%= post.like %></td>
  <td><%= link_to 'like', like_post_path(post), :remote => true %></td>
</tr>
```

**like.js.erb:**

```
$("#post_like_<%= post.id %>").html("<%= @post.like %>");
```

I can see the changes only after I refresh the page. Ajax is not working, but I failed to locate where the problem is in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `@` in your view. I see `$post` is in instance variable as I see `$post.like`. So, in your `like.js.erb`, replace `post.id` with `@post.id`. Like:

```
$("#post_like_<%= @post.id %>").html("<%= @post.like %>");
```

Comment: Great find! I cannot believe I spent hours not noticing this little problem.